# Trouble with Expression Encoder API

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, expression-encoder-sdk

I'm currently running Visual Studio Express Edition 2010, I downloaded Microsoft Expression Encoder API version 2. I installed it, but when I try to do a sample encoding, I don't find the Microsoft.Expression.Encoder, Encoder.Types and Encoder.Utilities dlls in the Add Reference window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc761462.aspx).  Scroll down to "To add the Expression Encoder assemblies".